# Document on MondoDB isn't being read. Using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Tried asking ChatGPT but looks like the old fashion way is always best...

I think I have my schema, controllers, and routes all correct, but it just keeps saying it found 0 documents in my console when I go to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/album. I'm not sure what can be wrong here, the schema seems true to my uploaded document. Here is what I have:

Index.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import connectDB from './mongodb/connect.js';
import cors from 'cors';

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

import userRouter from './mongodb/routes/user.routes.js'
import albumRouter from './mongodb/routes/album.routes.js'

// ** configs
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ message: "Hello" })
})

app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/album', albumRouter);

const serverInit = async () => {
    try {
        connectDB(process.env.MONGODB_URL);
        app.listen(8080, console.log('server on 8080'))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

serverInit();
```

album.js schema:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const AlbumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    album_id: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    artist: {type: String, required: true},
    label: {type: String, required: true},
    genre: {type: String, required: true},
    khz: {type: Number, required: true},
    bitrate: {type: Number, required: true},
    numTracks: {type: Number, required: true},
    runtime: {type: Number, required: true},
    parental: {type: Boolean, required: true},
}, { collection: 'app-data.albums' })

const albumModel = mongoose.model('Album', AlbumSchema)

export default albumModel;
```

album.routes.js:

```
import express from 'express';

import {
    getAllAlbums,
    getAlbumDetail
} from '../controllers/album.controller.js'

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get(getAllAlbums)
router.route('/:id').get(getAlbumDetail)

export default router;
```

And finally, the controller:

```
import User from '../models/user.js'
import Album from '../models/album.js'

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config();


const getAllAlbums = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('Retrieving all albums from the app-data.albums collection...');
        const albums = await Album.find({}).limit(req.query._end)  //find all albums in db

        console.log(`Found ${albums.length} albums`);

        res.status(200).json(albums)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message })
    }
}; 

const getAlbumDetail = async (req, res) => {}; 

export {
    getAllAlbums,
    getAlbumDetail
}
```

Here's the uploaded document:

[mongodb document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVIGp.png)

I'm really hoping that's not overkill, I just don't know how else to get help without posting all of this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `.limit(req.query._end)` -> you haven't set `_end` so the value is equivalent to 0. You're limiting the query to 0 documents.

Comment: You're right, I was misunderstanding the tutorial I was referring to when I added that. I shortened it just simple const albums = await Album.find({})  though and it still returns no results. I also tried "console.log(`Using collection: ${Album.collection.name}`);" and it correctly seems to be referring the right database on MongoDB. Why it still persists confuses me.

Comment: If the screenshot is from Mongo Cloud, the name of the collection is just "albums". "app-data" is the name of the database. You can also try to insert a document via code to confirm that the model points to the right collection.

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you mean? The code in my last comment console.logs "Using collection: albums" so that seems to be correct. I also changed my schema so the second argument is now { collection: 'albums'} but that doesn't seem to be having any different effect.

Comment: Look up how to insert a document with Mongoose (plenty of examples in google) and then check if it appears in the Cloud console.

Comment: Just figured it out and I feel stupid now. Thanks so much for taking the time out to help, though. The world needs more Guys.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the issue. It was simply because I had a second collection on the site that it was referring to instead that I had forgotten I made, and I just want to cry now... I gotta review the code to see why that specific collection was getting precedence over the others.